# How to build custom C# password validator using Delegates?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, lambda, delegates

I would like to build my own password validator using C# delegates.

My goal is to achive something like a pipeline through which the password will be validated.

```
public class Validator
{
    public static bool IsPasswordValid() =>
        ValidatePassword("password", (options) => 
            {
                options.HasMinLength(8);
                options.HasUpperCase();
            });

    public static bool ValidatePassword(string password, Action<ValidatorOptions> input)
    {
        // Can I somehow call the defined pipelien here and validate the password?
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ValidatorOptions
{
    public bool HasUpperCase() => true;
    public bool HasMinLength(int num) => true;
}
```

Am' I go in right direction? Is it even possible?

**UPDATE**

The `ValidatorOptions` class would have a many validation methods e.g. HasDigit(), HasLowerCase(), HasSpecialCharacter(5) etc. Btw these methods would use regex in their bodies.

This options would be published together with `ValidatePassword` method as a NuGet package. I would like to use this package for build dynamic pipeline with validation options which I am currently interested in for a given project.

The `ValidatePassword` method should validate the password through passed 'validators pipeline' as an argument. How to implement the `ValidatePassword` method?

Comment: Sure, what's the problem? Your `ValidatorOptions` class needs to record what methods were called on it, and your `ValidatePassword` class needs to query the `ValidatorOptions` instance to se which options were set, and then do the corresponding checks

Comment: Do you have a specific problem or are you seeking some sort of code review?

Comment: Surely you want a `Func<string, ValidatorOptions, bool>`? And I wonder if this entire thing could be done using just a regex?

Comment: Please, check my update.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marc Gravell I've already found the solution.

I had to replace `Action` to `Func` and add constructor to the `ValidatorOptions` class.

```
public class Validator
{
    public static bool IsPasswordValid() =>
        ValidatePassword("password", options => options.HasMinLength(8)
                && options.HasUpperChar());

    public static bool ValidatePassword(string password, Func<ValidatorOptions, bool> input)
    {
        var options = new ValidatorOptions(password);
        return input(options)
    }
}

public class ValidatorOptions
{
    public string Input { get; }

    public ValidatorOptions(string input) => Input = input;

    public bool HasUpperChar() => new Regex(@"[A-Z]+").IsMatch(Input);
    public bool HasMinLength(int length) => Input.lengt >= length;
}
```